# Extent of scattering of light

Tags: optics, visible-light, scattering, lenses

I am absolutely no expert in physics but I really want this question answered and the reputation of the forum is good. So my question is if I have a magnifying glass, for example, it can fix the light on a certain point. But this is often only a small point. Is it also possible with the help of a kind of magnifying glass or something else that you can focus the light on a larger area, so that more area is illuminated?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a lens will focus the light into a point only at a specific distance from the lens, where the image forms. If you look at a different distance, the point will be out of focus and spread into an area which will become larger as you become farther away from the point at which the light is focused. So just move the lens until the image of a point becomes the size you want.